# .tld's not working after switch from weblogic to tomcat/maven

Tags: java, tomcat, tags

I have seen a few questions on here about this, but no one seems to have an answer.  I am doing a migration from Weblogic and Java 6 to Tomcat and Java 8, and everything is going smoothly except for a couple of tag libraries we have.

This is the structure:

```
-src
    -main
        -java
            -misckPkg
                -tags.fav
                    - FavTagSupport.java
        -webapp
            -WEB-INF
                -fav.tld
            -faVer.jsp
```

Code snippet from FavTagSupport.java

```
    abstract class FavTagSupport extends TagSupport {
  protected FavEnum.type vType = null;

  public FavTagSupport() {
    super();
    this.init();
  }

  public FavEnum.type getVType() {
    return this.vType;
  }

  public void setVType(FavEnum.type vType) {
    this.vType = vType;
  }
```

Code snippet from fav.tld

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd">
<taglib>
  <tlib-version>1.1</tlib-version>
  <jsp-version>1.2</jsp-version>
  <short-name>fav</short-name>
  <uri>/WEB-INF/fav.tld</uri>

  <tag>
    <attribute>
      <name>vType</name>
      <required>true</required>
      <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
  </tag>
```

Code snippet from faVer.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/fav.tld" prefix="f" %>
```

Error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /faVer.jsp (line: 166, column: 6) Unable to find setter method for attribute: vType
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:275)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:107)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.evaluateAttribute(Generator.java:3003)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.generateSetters(Generator.java:3223)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.generateCustomStart(Generator.java:2404)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1901)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1536)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:464)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3646)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:250)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    miscPkg.LoggerFilter.doFilter(LoggerFilter.java:72)
```

EDIT: The more I mess with this, it becomes obvious that it is not finding my FavTagSupport class.  I am going to try moving it around, though I am not sure why that would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question, but it was a simple casing issue.  Change `getVtype` to `getvType` and `setVType` to `setvType`

Always understood that it should be cased with a capital from the attribute name, but I guess tomcat does it differently.